# Grid view icon redirects to different sites

Tags: android

I am referring to the site but all the icons using the Grid view redirects to the same site . What I need to do to add a different site each icon ?

enter code here

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Uri link = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.tr");
            Intent tara= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT,link);
            startActivity(tara);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext =c;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
     return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView==null){
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85,85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    }else{
        imageView=(ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

private Integer [] mThumbIds={
 R.drawable.turkey,R.drawable.brazil,R.drawable.canada,R.drawable.china,R.drawable.china,R.drawable.france,
        R.drawable.germany,R.drawable.india,R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.italy,R.drawable.japan,
        R.drawable.korea,R.drawable.mexico,R.drawable.netherlands,R.drawable.portugal,R.drawable.russia,
        R.drawable.saudi_arabia,R.drawable.spain,R.drawable.united_kingdom,R.drawable.united_states
};
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you select your images depending on position. So the easiest way would be to create another array with urls `private String[] urls = {"url1", "url2", ...};` in your MainActivity and map it tho the positions in your `onItemClick`-Method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Uri link = Uri.parse(urls[position]);
        Intent tara= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT,link);
        startActivity(tara);
}
```